# passing value from tab page in ionic

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to pass the value in "this.nav.get('ID')" from  the homepage to three other pages and I was wondering how I can do that and how to get the value in the pages since the homepage is just tabs

```
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public nav:NavParams){

    this.nav.get('ID')

    this.params.data=[ 

        {page:OffersPage,title:"offer"},
        {page:FavoritePage,title:"Favorite"},
        {page:SettingsPage,title:"setting"}
        ];
```

homepage.html

```
 <ion-tabs #tabs tabsPlacement="bottom">
    <ion-tab [tabTitle]="item.title" [root]="item.page" *ngFor="let item of data;let i = index"></ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to problem in this link http://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20170505-PassingDataBetweenTabsInIonic2.html